# How to create an arbitrary state for debugging purposes in the local computer?

Tags: q#, state-preparation

Is there a way to create an arbitrary state in Q# just for debugging purposes in the local computer via the quantum full state simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Modern QDK (version 1.*): You can use the library operations [PreparePureStateD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp-lang/microsoft.quantum.unstable.statepreparation/preparepurestated) (arbitrary real amplitudes) or [ApproximatelyPreparePureStateCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp-lang/microsoft.quantum.unstable.statepreparation/approximatelypreparepurestatecp) (complex amplitudes, with a possibility of approximate state preparation) to prepare an arbitrary state starting from the $|0..0\rangle$ state.

Classic QDK (version 0.*): You can use the library operations [PrepareArbitraryStateD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystated) (real non-negative amplitudes) or [PrepareArbitraryStateCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.preparation.preparearbitrarystatecp) (complex amplitudes) to prepare an arbitrary state starting from the $|0..0\rangle$ state.